# Bluetooth,Wifi with Bonjour Network

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, bonjour, cfnetwork, nsnetservice

If i am publishing a NSNetService in (Bonjour based NetWork) Iphone Application,which net Work will use in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the high-level NSNetService methods, (on both OS X and iOS) the `NSNetService` will be published through any network interface that supports multicast packet transport. Since bluetooth supports this, you should be able to broadcast mDNS data over a PAN, although service advertising and discovery may be slower than on a normal IP network. Have a read through [this](http://excitabyte.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/troubleshooting-bonjour-networking-for-the-iphone/) for more information.